# PHP/MySQL - Threading needs slightly different order

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a MySQL table with `id`, `parent` and `comment` which I managed to order almost-as-it-should from latest to oldest. If a comment has no parent, this is set to 0.

The `comments` table: [Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amdf8.png)

Hereby my current code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('host','username','password','database');

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$comments = array();
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
 $parent = $row['parent'];
 $comments[$parent ? $parent : 0][] = $row;                                        
}

function thread($parent,$comments) {
 foreach ($comments[$parent] as $post) {
  echo "<div>";
  echo $post['comment'];
  $id = $post['id'];
   if (isset($comments[$id])) {
    thread($id,$comments);
   }
  echo "</div>";
 }
}

thread(0,$comments);     

?>
```

The above results in the following order *(turned into a list for readability, you can do this in the code by turning the div tags into li and echoing ul tags around the foreach loop)*:

- Third comment
- Second comment

  - Another reply to the second comment

    - And another one
  - Reply to the second comment

    - Reply to a reply
- First comment

  - Reply to the first comment

Notice that replies are ordered in a descending manner as well, just like the comments. Other than that it's completely fine and working like a charm. But this is what it's supposed to be like:

- Third comment
- Second comment

  - **Reply to the second comment**

    - **Reply to a reply**
  - **Another reply to the second comment**

    - **And another one**
- First comment

  - Reply to the first comment

Shortly said: comments should be in descending order, replies in ascending. That is where I got stuck completely. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`array_reverse`](https://www.php.net/array_reverse) function to reverse the order of the items in an array:

```
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    // ...
}

// Important bit: Reverse all threads except the main thread (id=0):
foreach ($comments as $key => $value) {
    if ($key !== 0) {
        $comments[$key] = array_reverse($value);
    }
}

function thread($parent,$comments) {
    // And so on...
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't think of using parent for it. Of course $threads should actually be $comments in this particular case but it works exactly as it should! Thanks again!

Comment: Oh yes, I mixed up the variable names, I'll edit the answer. Glad I could help, though. :)